# WhatsApp QR scanner seems blurry

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera, qr-code

My WhatsApp QR scanner is not working when needed for WhatsApp Web. It seems blurry, while my phone's camera is actually perfectly clear.

Secondly, I have restarted the phone none worked, same issue not working. Thirdly, I have switched off the phone & again start, nothing worked out. Fourthly, I have tried using my corporate number and the QR scanner started in a micro second in WhatsApp Web.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a support ticket with Facebook to fix their app somehow, and in the meantime:

1. Press <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> to copy the screen to the clipboard.
2. Paste it in an image viewer like Paint.
3. Zoom it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or a slider.
4. Try the blurry WhatsApp scanner before the code changes.